# Does Redis need to be handled the same as disk storage?

Tags: node.js, redis, coffeescript

Im justing wondering, with redis being stored in memory, does access still need to be handled the same way as disk I/O?

Can you do stuff like...

```
X = redis.get X
#do stuff with X
```

or would you need to do...

```
redis.get X, (X) ->
    #do stuff with X
```

Comment: It's in memory, but it's in another process, it's still best practice to not block.

Comment: Thanks generalhenry, you should of tossed in an answer so I could give you credit for the insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Communication with redis occurs over sockets. Sockets are still I/O, and (nearly) all I/O in node is handled asynchronously. Yes, you need the callback.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what other answerers have said: Redis libraries allow you to connect with remote Redis hosts, in which case there's much more significant blocking. And Redis versions from 2.0 up to 2.4 support [virtual memory](http://redis.io/topics/virtual-memory), which means that you could, in principle, be reading from the disk.